# Angular page refresh - stay on the same component

Tags: angular, routes, page-refresh

So I have an Angular 14 application which has the following routes in my app-routing-module:

```
//FYI: URLS.ROUTE_BASE =  '/myApp/components',
// URLS.COMPONENT_ONE =  'componentOne',
// etc..
const routes: Routes = [
     { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
     { path: URLS.ROUTE_BASE, component: HomeComponent },
     { path: URLS.ROUTE_BASE + "/", component: HomeComponent },
     { path: URLS.COMPOMENT_ONE, component: ComponentOne },
     { path: URLS.COMPONENT_TWO, component: ComponentTwo },
     { path: URLS.COMPONENT_THREE, component: ComponentThree },
    ];
```

And then finally, they are collected as so:

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
      relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

So, when I load my Angular application, I am automatically routed to the HomeComponent. This is expected behavior. From the HomeComponent, the user is able to navigate to Components 1,2, or 3. For components 1 and 2, they accept URL parameters which are used in their respective OnInnit() methods (localhost:4200/myApp/components/componentTwo?id=123456789, for example).

The goal Im trying to accomplish is: the user should arrive on the home page, and can navigate to component 1,2, or 3. When they are on one of these pages, if they hit the browser refresh, they should *stay* on that page. If they are on component 1 or two, it should refresh that component, *and* use the same URL parameters it was originally passed. Those routines which are triggered in their onInit() methods should ideally just trigger again.

Current behavior is that when they hit the browser refresh button, it is immediately redirecting back to the home page.

I have seen several solutions saying that `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',` works for this, or making them child components, or including 'pathMatch:full' but I haven't had success.

Because this is an Angular single page application, I've also read that a browser refresh works as though the entire app was just loaded for the first time. So is this even possible from within a SPA ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comment out the second and third route and try again, i believe the third one is being matched because of the forward slash which isnt needed. Also, as a best practice, you should have one route with your HomeComponent, and then use `path: '', redirectTo: URLS.ROUTE_BASE, pathMatch: 'full'`.

Comment: I found there was some routing in my app-component.ts was causing the issue. 
But props for the best practice tip :)